# How to replace sharepoint 2010 library function in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, slidelibrary

We are planning for migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013; One of big problem is

How to recreate the Slide library functions?

Automation should improve processes, not create them and more work-flows.

Answer (score 0):

As part of migration this library will get migrated as a `Slide Library`. Slide Library belongs to feature id `{0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}` and it has the list template `2100`.

You can manually create a Slide Library by directly using the above information

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/15/slnew.aspx?FeatureId={0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}&ListTemplate=2100
```